# Add Facebook metadata to Rails pages with sub-pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, metadata

I've tried Facebook's Open Graph protocol in adding meta data on Rails pages. What I want to do now is to make my code not duplicated or D.R.Y.---instead of putting one meta-data header for each controller page I have, I'd like to create a base class called "MyMetaBuilder" which will be inherited by the sub-pages, but don't know where and how to start coding it...
Someone suggested that meta data property values must be dynamically generated depending on the context. For example, PlayMetaBuilder, CookMetaBuilder and so on...

Also, when unit testing the controller action, how do I verify for its existence?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is defining the tags, another is rendering them. I would do the following:

- write a controller mixin (something like acts_as_metatagable) where I would define specific fields for each controller (and populate the remaining with defaults). These would be assigned to a class (or instance) variable and in this way be made accessible in the rendering step).
- write an helper function which would take all my tags and turn them into html. This helper function would then be called in the layout and be rendered in the head of the document.

so, it would look a bit like this:
    # homepage_controller.rb
    class HomepageController < ActionController::Base
      # option 1.2: include it directly here with the line below
      # include ActsAsMetatagable
      acts_as_metatagable :title => "Title", :url => homepage_url
    end

```
# lib/acts_as_metatagable.rb
module ActsAsMetatagable
  module MetatagableMethods
    #option 2.2: insert og_tags method here and declare it as helper method
    def og_metatags
      @og_tags.map do |k, v|
        # render meta tags here according to its spec
      end
    end
    def self.included(base)
       base.helper_method :og_tags
    end
  end

  def acts_as_metagabable(*args)
    include MetatagableMethods
    # insert dirty work here
  end
end

# option 1.1: include it in an initializer
# initializers/acts_as_metatagable.rb
ActiveController::Base.send :include, ActsAsMetatagable


# option 2.1: insert og_metatags helper method in an helper
module ApplicationHelper
  def og_metatags
    @og_tags.map do |k, v|
      # render meta tags here according to its spec
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this @ChuckE. May I know in what directory or file would I put the above example?.. Is it in a single file only?
I'm a total newbie with this..

What I did before was put each meta tags inside `<head></head>` of every show.html.erb files...

Comment: I usually place mixins in the lib, and include them either in the class directly or in an initializer. The helper method is debatable. Either placing it in an helper directly, or keep it into it's context by defining it in the controller mixin and declare it as helper method: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method . I will edit my example a bit.

Answer (score 0):

What I did for Scoutzie, was put all metadata into a head partial, with if/else cases as such:

```
%meta{:type => 'Author', :content => "Kirill Zubovsky"}
%meta{'property' => "og:site_name", :content=>"Scoutzie"}
-if @designer
 ...
-elsif @design
 ...
-else
 ...
```

This way, depending on the variables that load, I know which page it is, and thereby know which metadata to include. This might not be an elegant solution, but it works and it's really simple.